# how to change column colour base on a condition in powershell html

Tags: html, powershell, reporting

Firstly i would apologize if i was asking a very noob question, i'm a beginner powershell users and i don't have much exp in scripting, i have some issue to output html report using powershell. I wanted to change the colour of each row according to the utilization % wheter it is above or below 90%. However i only manage to change the colour of the first row.

i have 2 file which i use to output the report.

output from agg.csv

```
Aggregate_01_Data1,10.01TB,90%,96.93TB,online,86.92TB,
Aggregate_02_Data1,9.03TB,91%,96.93TB,online,87.90TB,
root_Aggregate_01,17.85GB,85%,368.4GB,online,350.6GB,
root_Aggregate_02,17.85GB,95%,368.4GB,online,350.6GB,
```

output from aggregate.csv

```
Aggregate,Size,Available,Used,Utilized,State
Aggregate_01_Data1,96.93TB,10.01TB,86.92TB,90,online
Aggregate_02_Data1,96.93TB,9.03TB,87.90TB,91,online
root_Aggregate_01,368.4GB,17.85GB,350.6GB,85,online
root_Aggregate_02,368.4GB,17.85GB,350.6GB,95,online
```

my code to generate the html report.

```
$a1=gc $TPATH\agg.csv
$b1 =$a1 

 for ($i1 = 0;$i1 -lt $a1.count;$i1++)
 {
  $c1=$b1[$i1].split(",",10)
  $c = $c1[2].Length
  $c = $c - 1
  
  $d1=$c1[0] + "," + $c1[3] + "," + $c1[1] + "," + $c1[5] + "," + $c1[2].remove($c)  + "," + $c1[4]
  $d1 | Out-File ("$TPATH\aggregate.csv") -Encoding UTF8 -append

 $bodyB = (import-csv $TPATH\aggregate.csv) |Select Aggregate,Size,Available,Used,Utilized,State -OutVariable ag | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment |
 foreach { if($ag.Utilized -gt 90) {$_ -replace "<tr>", "<tr bgcolor=#FE0808>"}else{$_ -replace "<tr>", "<tr bgcolor=#E5FCA1>"}} |Out-String 

 }     
convertTo-HTML -Body "<br> $bodyB" |out-file $PATH\Netapp.html
```

my final output look like this

[image]

how can i get the output to be like this, i want to have the colour change to Red if the threshold is above 90% in the Utilized column and Green if the threshold is below 90%.
[image]

Thank you in advance for those whom willing to help, really appreciate your help in this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `-OutVariable ag` with `-PipelineVariable ag`, so that `$ag` in your `foreach` (`ForEach-Object`) script block refers only to the *single input object at hand*.

- The purpose of the [common `-PipelineVariable` (`-pv`) parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-pipelinevariable) is to store the *current* object being output in a self-chosen variable, so that it can be accesses in a script block later in the *same pipeline*.
- By contrast, the purpose of the [common `-OutVariable` (`-ov`) parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-outvariable) is to collect *all* output from a command in a self-chosen variable, for later processing in a *different, subsequent* statement, not in the same pipeline.

  - If you do access such a variable in a script block in the *same* pipeline, you'll see the output objects *accumulated so far* (which explains the behavior you saw - see below).

---

As for **what you tried**:

Due to the mistaken use of `-OutVariable ag`, your script block saw the `Import-Csv` output objects *collected so far* in variable `$ag` rather than the output object at hand.

Thus, starting with the second output object, `$ag` was in effect an *array* of objects, and accessing its `. Utilized` property resulted in [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration), and therefore returning an *array* of utilization values.

Since `-gt`, like all PowerShell comparison operators, acts as a *filter* when its LHS is an *array*, `$ag.Utilized -gt 90` started to generate a return value (the subarray of matching values) as soon as at least *one* element in the array of values satisfied this condition.

In a Boolean context such as an `if`-statement conditional, a non-empty array is interpreted as `$true`.

Therefore, in effect `($ag.Utilized -gt 90)` returned `$true` as soon as the *first* value above `90` was part of the return array, and invariably *remained* true.

Comment: Thank you for your help.. however i had another issue where the header of the table follow the first row colour. how can i maintain the haeader to be blue like previously..

Comment: it's ok.. it seem like my styling has something to do with that.. :) thanks a bunch..

Comment: Glad to hear it all worked out, @FaizalIzham; my pleasure.